# Synchronize method with spreed

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I use spring boot and mysql in a web application.

This application  use tomcat

I need to generate a value who will be inserted in the database.

I want to avoid to have multiple tread who access method in the same time.

I would like to know if using **synchronized** with spring is the way to go for this issue.

Comment: please add code to understand your requirement.

Comment: `synchronized` is almost never the way to go when you have Spring and a database.  You want transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `synchronized method` or `synchronized block with single or multiple monitor lock` to achieve this. But, there are other ways around like: `ExecutorService,Countdown latch, Producer-consumer approach etc`.I suggest you do some research and pick the appropriate approach which you find convincing.

As for the synchronized method is concern, Here I have demonstrated a situation where two threads invoke a common method  **increment()** and that common method tries to change a shared data **counter** between threads.

```
public class App {

// this is a shared data between two threads.
private int counter = 0;


//this method is invoked from both threads.
private synchronized void increment() {
    counter++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();
    app.doWork();
}


private void doWork() {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            increment();
        }
    });

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            increment();
        }
    });

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(" The counter is :" + counter); 
   //output shoud be equal to : 20000
  }
}
```

Now, try removing keyword `synchronized` from the method `increment()`, re-compile the code and see the nature of output it produces.